# Unable to directly access variable oss.Caption from objWMIService.ExecQuery

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am just trying to get the OS Caption which says something like "Windows 8.1 Enterprise" but I have to access it using a loop, and setting the variable in that loop, `strSearchString = os.Caption`. Why can't I just do `strSearchString = oss.Caption` or just reference `oss.Caption`?

Sample Code:  If not Windows 8 give error.

```
Sub Windows8_Enterprise_Check
  'OS Determination
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
                      & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
  Set oss = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
  For Each os in oss
    strSearchString = os.Caption
  Next

  strSearchFor1 = "Windows 8"
  strSearchFor2 = "Enterprise"

  If (InStr(1, strSearchString, strSearchFor1) < 1) _
       OR (InStr(1, strSearchString, strSearchFor2) < 1) Then
    'We didn't find strSearchFor in strSearchString
    Wscript.Echo "OS Level Error: " & strSearchString _
      & " is invalid for this script"
    WScript.Quit(49)
  Else
    Wscript.Echo "OS Level Test: PASS"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `oss` returned by the query is a collection. Items/Elements of the collection have a .Caption property, but the collection has not.

Answer (score 0):

When you query WMI, by default it return the list/collection of objects where each object holds the property data for the class.

So when you say oss, think it as array of object where each object (that is os in your case)

Oss is

```
Oss(0)
Oss(1)
Oss(2)… likewise
```

So when you say os, it will be pointing to one of the objects from above listed.
Now you can think 
    os=Oss(0)

Where Oss(0) has different properties where one of them is caption.
Hence you need to point to individual object and then access the property inside..